# Is there a way to create an enhanced casting on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, casting

I want to create an enhanced casting on my iOS app.
In simple words, I want to be able to customise the view that's on the screen the user is casting into.

UI for example:

- User is watching a video on iOS device.
- User clicks on airplay to cast the video to an external device, such as a TV.
- Device's screen still showing the video, but on the external device the display contains the video with some customise widgets on it, and a window showing the camera coming from the iOS mobile.

I couldn't find any related information on web, maybe you'll have an idea on what can I do? and what is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this?  It's OC rather than Swift but the concepts might help.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html